# How do I add a custom onClicklistener for my spinner with checkboxes

Tags: java, android, checkbox, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I've been trying to implement a multi-select spinner on my own. So the problem is I'm able to select the checkboxes but when I close and open the spinner again, the selected checkboxes get deselected. So I thought I would implement my own itemclick listener to the spinner and use the positions to check the checkboxes. Now, my spinner is not dropping down.

Here's the code for the main activity.

```
public class MyProfileActivity extends Activity implements 
    View.OnClickListener, SpinnerMultiSelectAdapter.OnListItemClickListener{      

    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

       lang_spinner_profile = findViewById(R.id.lang_spinner_profile);

       ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<>();
       options.add("English");
       options.add("Japanese");
       options.add("Chinese");
       options.add("Korean");

       lang_spinner_profile.setSelection(0);

       final String[] languages = {
            "Select Language", "English","Chinese","Japanese","Korean"};

       for (int j = 0; j < languages.length; j++) {
           StateVO stateVO= new StateVO();
           stateVO.setTitle(languages[j]);
           stateVO.setSelected(false);
           listVOs.add(stateVO);
       }
       Log.d("Called","Called");

       myAdapter = new SpinnerMultiSelectAdapter(MyProfileActivity.this, 0,
            listVOs, this);
       lang_spinner_profile.setAdapter(myAdapter);
   }

   @Override
   public void onListItemClick(int position) {
     Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked at: "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
}
```

This is my custom pojo class for the spinner.

```
public class StateVO {
   private String title;
   private boolean selected;
   private String selectedItem;


   public String getTitle() {
      return title;
   }

   public void setTitle(String title) {
      this.title = title;
   }

   public boolean isSelected() {
      return selected;
   }

   public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
      this.selected = selected;
   }
}
```

This is the spinner custom layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/text"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
       android:text="text"
       android:textAlignment="gravity" />

   <CheckBox
       android:id="@+id/checkbox"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And finally, this is my custom adapter.

```
public class SpinnerMultiSelectAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<StateVO> {
   private Context mContext;
   static private ArrayList<StateVO> listState;
   private SpinnerMultiSelectAdapter myAdapter;
   private boolean isFromView = false;
   List<String> selected = new ArrayList<>();
   static int i=0;
   List<Integer> checked= new ArrayList<>();

   View itemView;
   int getPosition;

   private OnListItemClickListener onListItemClickListener;

   public SpinnerMultiSelectAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<StateVO> objects, OnListItemClickListener onListItemClickListener) {
       super(context, resource, objects);
       this.mContext = context;
       this.listState = (ArrayList<StateVO>) objects;
       this.myAdapter = this;
       this.onListItemClickListener = onListItemClickListener;
   }

   @Override
   public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                            ViewGroup parent) {
       return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
   }

   public View getCustomView(final int position, View convertView,
                          ViewGroup parent) {

       final ViewHolder holder;
       if (convertView == null) {
           LayoutInflater layoutInflator = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
           convertView = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item, null);
           itemView = convertView;
           holder = new ViewHolder();
           holder.mTextView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.text);
           holder.mCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
           convertView.setTag(holder);
       } else {
           holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
       }

       holder.mTextView.setText(listState.get(position).getTitle());

       // To check weather checked event fire from getview() or user input
       isFromView = true;
       holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(listState.get(position).isSelected());
       isFromView = false;

       if ((position == 0)) {
           holder.mCheckBox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
       } else {
           holder.mCheckBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       }
       holder.mCheckBox.setTag(position);
       selected.clear();
       holder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
               getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
               holder.mCheckBox.setSelected(true);
               //notifyDataSetChanged();
           }
       });
       return convertView;
   }

   private class ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
       private TextView mTextView;
       private CheckBox mCheckBox;

       public ViewHolder(){
           itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
       }

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           onListItemClickListener.onListItemClick(getPosition);
       }
   }
   public interface OnListItemClickListener {
       public void onListItemClick(int position);
   }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: In where you are creating the adapter ?

Comment: If you mean where I'm calling,  I call it in the main activity, the first part of my code.@ErginErsoy

Comment: @HarshadPrajapati Thank you, but I've checked the link before and I don't want the spinner to open in a new alert box. I want it to drop down with the checkboxes.

Comment: can you update main activity section in your question to show where you create adapter in onclick in oncreate where ?

Comment: I've updated my question, check it out

Answer (score 1):

Your adapter has few mistakes here is how it should be;

```
public class SpinnerMultiSelectAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<StateVO> {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<StateVO> listState;
    private boolean isFromView = false;
    List<String> selected = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> checked = new ArrayList<>();
    private OnListItemClickListener onListItemClickListener;

    public SpinnerMultiSelectAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<StateVO> objects, OnListItemClickListener onListItemClickListener) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.listState = (ArrayList<StateVO>) objects;
        this.onListItemClickListener = onListItemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                                ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public View getCustomView(final int position, View convertView,
                              ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflator = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            convertView = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        final String str = listState.get(position).getTitle();
        holder.mTextView.setText(str);
        if ((position == 0)) {
            holder.mCheckBox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.mCheckBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        holder.mCheckBox.setTag(position);
        holder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                listState.get(position).setSelected(isChecked);
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private TextView mTextView;
        private CheckBox mCheckBox;

        public ViewHolder(View convertView) {
            mTextView = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.text);
            mCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
            convertView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /*onListItemClickListener.onListItemClick(getPosition);*/
        }
    }

    public interface OnListItemClickListener {
        public void onListItemClick(int position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I appreciate it. I think I have found another solution to the problem. I simply used the "isfromview" to check if it's fired from the user or view and used if else to set the checkbox value accordingly.

Comment: Ok. But need to delete holder.mCheckbox.setselected(true) line in oncheckchange. Because it is useless and even if it is not checked you are check it again.

Comment: I guess we should be using setChecked() instead of setSelected().

Comment: even so you shouldn't put in your `onCheckChange()`